# Shopify LinkList Loop Using Dynamic Variables

Tags: shopify

I have a block of code that I use on several pages.  The only thing that changes in this block of code is the variable for the linklist.  How do I refactor this code so that I can use a variable instead of static code?

```
<div class="featured-collections">
  <div class="frow justify-start">
    {% for link in linklists.book.links %}
    <div class="collection-thumb">
      <img class="collection-thumb-img" src="{{ link.object.featured_image | img_url: 'medium' }}">
      <h3 class="collection-thumb-title">
        <a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.object.title | escape }}</a><br/>
      </h3>
      {{ link.object.price | money }}<br/>
      <p>Book Now</p>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
// Code for Variable Component - variable-linklist.liquid
{% for link in linklists.c.links %}
...
{% endfor %}

// Code for Book Page - page.book.liquid
{% assign c = "book" %}
{% include "variable-linklist" with "c" %}
```

but this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for Book Page - page.book.liquid

```
{% assign c = "book" %}
{% include "variable-linklist" with linklistHandle: c %}
```

Code for Variable Component - variable-linklist.liquid

```
{% for link in linklists[linklistHandle].links %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

or

Code for Book Page - page.book.liquid

```
{% assign c = "book" %}
{% include "variable-linklist" with c %}
```

Code for Variable Component - variable-linklist.liquid

```
{% for link in linklists[variable-linklist].links %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

When you use just `with c` the value is assigned to the variable with a name that is equal to the snippet name.